# Pandas: Adding incremental numbers to the suffix of repeating values of a column that are grouped by the value of another column and ordered by index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add an underscore and incremental numbers to any repeating values ordered by index and within a group that is defined by another column.

For example, I would like the repeating values in the Chemistry column to have underscores and incremental numbers ordered by index and grouped by the Cycle column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2], ['NaOH', 'H20', 'MWS', 'H20', 'MWS', 'NaOh', 'NaOH', 'H20', 'MWS', 'H20', 'MWS', 'NaOh']]).transpose()
df.columns = ['Cycle', 'Chemistry']
df
```

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkuPZ.png)

So the output will look like the table in the link below:

[Desired output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rxrH.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

#### `pandas.Series.str.cat` and `cumcount`

```
df['Chemistry'] = df.Chemistry.str.cat(
    df.groupby(['Cycle', 'Chemistry']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str),
    sep='_'
)

df

   Cycle Chemistry
0      1    NaOH_1
1      1     H20_1
2      1     MWS_1
3      1     H20_2
4      1     MWS_2
5      1    NaOh_1
6      2    NaOH_1
7      2     H20_1
8      2     MWS_1
9      2     H20_2
10     2     MWS_2
11     2    NaOH_2
```

Comment: I tried your code, however it returned the original table. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did not assign the result of that code back to the dataframe.  That is why you still see the original dataframe unchanged.  I'll edit the post.... I've updated the post.